# How to compare features of two different annotations within a Ruta rule?

Tags: java, uima, ruta

I am processing a text with UIMA Ruta and want to remove duplicated annotations. I consider an annotation to be duplicated if certain features, for instance a name, have the same value. I have unsuccessfully tried different approaches, but I hope the following examples will give an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
STRING nameVal;
Person {-> GETFEATURE("name", nameVal)}  
ANY+? 
Person.name == nameVal {-> UNMARK(Person)};
```

I have also tried this variation:

```
STRING nameVal;
Person {-> GETFEATURE("name", nameVal)}  
ANY+? 
Person {-> UNMARK(Person)} <- { Person.name == nameVal; };
```

If I replace the variable nameVal with a literal (see next example), the rules work well and seem to be close to what I want, but not quite.

```
Person
ANY+? 
Person.name == "Mustermann" {-> UNMARK(Person)};
```

I believe, the problem is that, when the comparison is evaluated, the global variable has not yet been initialized. Is there a way in Ruta to compare a feature of the first matched annotation with a feature of the last matched annotation inside the same rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that the actions are executed when the complete rule has matched after all conditions are evaluated. You need an action to assign the feature value to a variable, but you need a condition for comparing the variable to another feature.

However, there are many ways to solve this in Ruta nevertheless, e.g., with more rules, BLOCK or action inlined rules. The best way are label expression. UIMA Ruta 2.5.0 makes our life much easier here. You can write something like this:

```
p1:Person # p2:Person{p1.name == p2.name -> UNMARK(Person)};
```

or

```
p1:Person # Person.name==p1.name{ -> UNMARK(Person)};
```

You can probably write a faster rule if you use a STRINGLIST: If the value is contained in the list, then unmark the annotation, if not, then add the value to the list.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Actually, I also tried that. Does it work only in UIMA Ruta 2.5.0 (I have not upgraded yet)? When using Ruta embedded in an AE, is some configuration required? I will check it out tomorrow at work.

Comment: Yes, it only works in UIMA Ruta 2.5.0 which supports feature epxressions on label expressions like `p1.name`.

Comment: I did some testing now, and unfortunately it didn't work. After updating the eclipse plugins, I get an `IllegalArgumentException` with the message "Passed arguments are invalid!" when running Ruta on a test project using the Ruta Workbench. In a project where the Ruta egine runs embedded, a set of rules that works well under Ruta 2.4.0  generates a `RutaParseRuntimeException` under Ruta 2.5.0. I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2), Ruta Workbench 2.5.0 and UIMA Tools and runtime 2.9.0. Are there any issues I should be aware of?

Comment: The first exception indicates that the launcher and the launch config are not compatible. Can you delete the Run Configuration and create a new one. e.g., just by running the script? For the second exception, I need more information.

Comment: Yes, that was my impression too, but I don't know how to debug Eclipse plugins, so I didn't get further. I suggest to concentrate on the first problem, if you don't mind. I usually test new rules on the workbench before moving them to the embedded engine. I just did the following: I imported the ExampleProject from the 2.5.0 sources, after fixing a syntax problem in Year.ruta, I tried to run the script and got the `IllegalArgumentException`. Same thing for a newly created UIMA Ruta Project.

Comment: I just downloaded Eclipse Neon and installed the UIMA tools, just to check if the problem could be caused by something going wrong during the update. Performed the same tests as described in my previous comment and got exactly the same results. I am testing all this on a Windows 8 box with Java 1.8.0_102 (just to provide more complete details on my testing environment).

Comment: The problem is caused by an activated preference. The solution is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887957/ruta-versions-2-5-0