# Ruta Versions 2.5.0

Tags: version, uima, ruta

I'm Updated the latest version Of Uima Ruta (2.5.0). After Updated the Version while I'm running the Script in Eclipse(MARS 2.0)..  Getting the error Like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed arguments are invalid!
at [![Ruta IDE Error ][1]][1]org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:144).
```

.could not run anymore files..

Comment: I actually do not know why it doesn't work. But it must be that a different version of UIMA Ruta is in the classpath of your project. Are there still older plugins installed (dropins), is it a java project with a classpath, is it a maven project with dependencies?

Comment: It's a Ruta Project

Comment: Finally found the problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by a preference that is falsely activated.

In the menu go to "Window" -> "Preferences". Then, select "UIMA Ruta" -> "Project Management", and uncheck the preference "Do not start a VM in development mode."

[image: UIMA Ruta preferences]

This error can also happen if the descriptor of the script is invalid or does not exist. If the above preference oes not help, validate the descriptor.