# Uima ruta - uima caseditor

Tags: uima, ruta

I've updated ruta 2.5.0 and I got the output but, when I tried to view the output I'm receiving this problem org/apache/uima/caseditor/editor/CasEditorViewPage$1.

Comment: Again I did the updation process I received  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed arguments are invalid!
at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:144)

Comment: Can you extend the probelm description a bit? Are the plugins (uima+ruta) started correctly? Are the log entries in eclipse?

Comment: Hi Peter, I receiving this error message now in the ruta project "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed arguments are invalid! at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLau‌​ncher.java:144)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1: org/apache/uima/caseditor/editor/CasEditorViewPage$1.

Right-click on the UIMA Ruta project and select "UIMA Ruta -> Convert to UIMA Ruta project", which will update all provided descriptors. Then, select the project and press "Project -> Clean..."

Issue 2:  For Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed arguments are invalid! at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLau‌​ncher.java:144) issue view the link.
 [Ruta Versions 2.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887957/ruta-versions-2-5-0/39953505#39953505)