# Error while running Apache UIMA Ruta Workbench 2.5.0 on Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon, ruta

I'm trying to run **Apache UIMA Ruta Workbench 2.5.0** on **Eclipse Neon** (both Windows and Linux), but the execution of the script (any script) gets terminated and the following error message shows up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed arguments are invalid!
at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:144)
```

The solution in [Ruta Versions 2.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887957/ruta-versions-2-5-0/39953505#39953505) is not adequate, as in my case all options under *"Project Management"* were already unchecked upon installation.

Would anybody have any ideas as to why I keep getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Solution]

Checkin Update Source Document information when launching a script

Comment: Right-click on the UIMA Ruta project and select "UIMA Ruta -> Convert to UIMA Ruta project", which will update all provided descriptors. Then, select the project and press "Project -> Clean..."